# Directive - getting values from views -scope "@"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make a button, which changes its styles every time it's clicked.

The console keeps making errors - 'initial' is not defined. I've been trying to figure out why but so far no luck.

Is this a wrong way to receive a value from the view?

Moreover, I made a click event in the link function but it seems not even working.

It would be great if you can help me understand how to make an effective angular directive! Thanks!

---

html

```
<div button-ok initial="glyphicon-plus" after="glyphicon-ok" base="glyphicon"></div>
```

I made a directive called "button-ok"

```
  myapp

      .run(function($templateCache) {
         var button;

         button = "<div class='btn btn-default'></div>";
         $templateCache.put('okbutton.html', button);
      })

      .directive('buttonOk', function($templateCache) {
          var icon;

          icon = angular.element("<i></i>");

          return {
               restrict: 'EA',
               scope: {
                   initial: "@",
                   after  : "@",
                   base   : "@"
               },
               replace : true,
               template: $templateCache.get('okbutton.html'),
               compile: function(tElem) {

                    icon.addClass(base);           
                    icon.addClass(initial);

                    tElem.append(icon);

               },
               link: function(scope, elem) {

                  elem.click(function() {
                     if(icon.hasClass(initial)){
                         icon.removeClass(initial);
                         icon.addClass(after);
                     }else{
                         icon.removeClass(after);
                         icon.addClass(initial);                       
                     }
                  }); 
               }
            };
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initial` is on the scope, so it needs to be accessed with `scope.initial` (same with `base` and `after`). This also means you don't have access to it in the `compile()` function and the code in there needs to be moved to `link()`.